# Tomcat: multiple log4j.xml configs being used

Tags: spring, tomcat, log4j

I'm trying to standardise on log4j for logging in some existing web applications in Tomcat 7, but I can't get it to do exactly what I want.

I'm setting a `log4jConfigLocation` context parameter for each webapp, and the `web.xml` has a `Log4jConfigListener` set up. In itself that's working fine. But, if there's also a `log4j.xml` file in `WEB-INF/classes`, then that gets processed ***as well***, and *before* the intended file is processed. (I found this out by setting the `log4j.debug` property.)

I suspect it's down to the order of initialisation of the various parts of the system, but I don't want any legacy config files to clash with the new config files (that would cause confusion and delay) so how can I make it ignore `WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml` completely?

`WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
  <listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class> 
  </listener> 
</web-app>
```

`META-INF/context.xml`:

```
<Context swallowOutput="true" useNaming="false">
  <Parameter name="log4jConfigLocation" value="META-INF/log4j.xml" override="false"/>
  <Parameter name="log4jExposeWebAppRoot" value="false" override="false"/>
  ...
```

`META-INF/log4j.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <!-- Component appender -->
  <appender name="ATLAS-CORE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/services/atlas-core.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  ...
```

`WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml` (which uses the "wrong" log file!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <!-- Component appender -->
  <appender name="ATLAS-CORE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/services/booblyboo.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  ...
```

From Tomcat's STDOUT log:

```
2015-08-24 14:17:58 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader WebappClassLoader
  context: /atlas-core
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@531e3c55
.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/Dev/System/Tomcat-Atlas/webapps/atlas-core/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "null".
log4j: Ignoring debug attribute.
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.procserve] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.procserve is  [info].
log4j: com.procserve level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\Dev\System\Tomcat-Atlas/logs/services/booblyboo.log].
log4j: Setting property [append] to [true].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: C:\Dev\System\Tomcat-Atlas/logs/services/booblyboo.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Appender [ATLAS-CORE] to be rolled at midnight.
log4j: Adding appender named [ATLAS-CORE] to category [com.procserve].
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.springframework] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.springframework is  [warn].
log4j: org.springframework level set to WARN
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.hibernate] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.hibernate is  [warn].
log4j: org.hibernate level set to WARN
log4j: Level value for root is  [warn].
log4j: root level set to WARN
log4j: Adding appender named [ATLAS-CORE] to category [root].
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "null".
log4j: Ignoring debug attribute.
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.procserve] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.procserve is  [info].
log4j: com.procserve level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\Dev\System\Tomcat-Atlas/logs/services/atlas-core.log].
log4j: Setting property [append] to [true].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: C:\Dev\System\Tomcat-Atlas/logs/services/atlas-core.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Appender [ATLAS-CORE] to be rolled at midnight.
log4j: Adding appender named [ATLAS-CORE] to category [com.procserve].
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.springframework] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.springframework is  [warn].
log4j: org.springframework level set to WARN
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.hibernate] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.hibernate is  [warn].
log4j: org.hibernate level set to WARN
log4j: Level value for root is  [warn].
log4j: root level set to WARN
log4j: Adding appender named [ATLAS-CORE] to category [root].
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of an answer, and a sort of solution.

`WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml` is loaded automatically by Log4j when the log4j jar-file is loaded, as described in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit (ie the FM). That's before the web app gets as far as reading the `context.xml`, or doing anything with what is read, so setting `log4jConfigLocation` has no effect.

It is possible to stop `WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml` being loaded automatically by setting `log4j.defaultInitOverride`. However, that means that there are no Log4j settings in effect when the web app framework (Spring in this case) starts up. Spring starts trying to log things before it has got as far as processing the context settings and initialising Log4j.

In theory it might be possible to set `log4j.configuration` before the log4j jar-file is loaded, but I couldn't make that work.

In the end I decided to put the default logging configuration in `WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml` instead of make it a defined part of the web app "context". If the settings need to be adjusted in deployment, then the Tomcat Catalina context can be overridden:

`META-INF/context.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!-- No schema/DTD can be provided for this file
     (see http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=104205666221372&w=2) -->

<!-- By default, the atlas-core webapp's context is configured by this file
     The entire file can be overridden by creating a file in
     .../tomcat-installation/conf/catalina/localhost/atlas-core.xml
     (For simplicity, copy this file there as a template) -->

<Context swallowOutput="true" useNaming="false">
    <!-- These parameters are set not be overridden by a context-param in web.xml,
         but see comment above for a different way to override this whole file -->

    <!-- If you override this file to change the logging settings, then you might
         want to uncomment the following line, and copy WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml
         to .../tomcat-installation/conf/log4j/atlas-core.xml to make changes -->
    <!--
    <Parameter name="log4jConfigLocation" value="file:${catalina.base}conf/log4j/atlas-core.xml" override="false"/>
    -->
    <Parameter name="log4jRefreshInterval" value="600000" override="false"/>
    <Parameter name="log4jExposeWebAppRoot" value="false" override="false"/>
...
```

This does mean that the default log4j settings will be in effect for a short time at the very beginning of webapp initialisation, but I think that's close enough.